# Define a "contains" logic in match param when defining a Route in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there a way (or what is the best way, if more exist) to tell react router (v4) to include a component when a route **contains** something?

Example:

say  pattern is `/users/:id`, all the fallowing routes should match:

- `/users/111`
- `home/users/111`
- `article/123/users/111`
- `/users/111/article/123`
- `home/users/111/article/123`

EDIT: the rule should apply dynamically, i.e. without needs to enumerate all the possible routes: `/.*\/users\/:id.*/`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the switch?

if you dont use exact

```
<Route path="/" component={Home}/>
```

then every path will return this route, if you do

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
```

only leaving the pathname empty will return this route.

if you want to have several pathnames returning the same route you can use multiple `Route`s with/without exact, whatever you prefer.

Something like:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/:id" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/:id/article" component={Home}/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

This wil return `Home` if the pathname is empty, 123 , 123/article or 123/article/"whatever you put here".

If this doesnt fit your needs you can create a workaround with putting a Route on the end of the Switch which always returns Home, and when it does, passes the needed matches. Then you can use the Home component to insert your own logic.

```
const PageRouter = ({match}) => {
    if (match.params.someParameter !== "legit") {
        history.replace("/not-found");
    }
    return <HomePage/>
};
```